# django upload image to S3, (work on localhost but gives access denied error on server)

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto3

error: an error occurred (accessdenied) when calling the putobject operation access denied

I am having problem in uploading image to s3 from django, it works fine on local host, but gives access denied error on server with same credentials. here are my settings

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', '***')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', '***')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME', 'my-static-files')
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = os.environ.get('AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE', False)
```

note: I only want to upload image to s3 not all of my static files

Comment: You should not post credentials public on SO. These posts are public for the rest of the internet and there are some bad guys hanging around.. ;)

Comment: You should also be invalidating these tokens. Even If you edit your question, these are no longer secret.

Comment: those were dummy credentials